# NFSv4 server Errors

Tags: nfs4

I have an nfs server exporting /homes and clients mount this using sssd and ldap. Everything works fine. But, i recently created a central rsyslog server and all my nodes log to this server and I found a couple of error messages as below.

rpc.idmapd[15353]: nss_getpwnam: name '10092' does not map into domain

Should I be worried?
When i googled this a lot of threads suggested adding domain in idmap.conf but that didn't help getting rid of the error. I appreciate your houghts on this thank you

Comment: this means that some uids cant be mapped to names. If it only for some users - no worries.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a user who can't access their home directory, this would be why (the server isn't able to map their local UID to an account it recognizes, hence this error message).

If there is such a user, you'll want to figure out why they're not being mapped (could be due to misconfiguration of either the server or client).

Otherwise, it's not a particularly big issue and can probably be ignored.